# tensorflow slim fix bias, train weights

Tags: tensorflow

What is the best way to create a slim fully connected layer with fixed biases? Currently I have:

```
fc = slim.fully_connected(inputs, num_outputs = 10)
```

but the fully_connected function only allows fixing both the weights and biases at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that if you pass in an identity normalizer_fn, no biases are created and this is good enough for me:

```
fc = slim.fully_connected(normed, num_outputs = self.nInternalUnits, normalizer_fn=lambda x: x )
```